# moving publishing pages from root site to subsites, all html code are displaying as plain text

Tags: page-layout, richhtmlfield

We are using SP2013 on-premise. Publishing infrastructure is enabled in a site collection.

Recently we need to move all pages (*.aspx files under /Pages/ library) from root site to a subsite in same site collection. So we use the tool at **Site Settings -> Mange Content and Structure**, select the pages and then "**Move**" to subsite.

We have customized page layout named "HomePagelayout.aspx". The moved pages are still referring this layout. The layout contains several RichHtmlField. Now all the content (rich html code) are displaying `(e.g. <table width="100%" class="home-contentbox-title" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="height: 32px;"><tbody><tr><td><span id="ms-rterangecursor-start" rtenodeid="1"></span>)`

When we "Edit" the page (change to edit mode) the display are completely alright. The html codes are rendering correctly. However when we "Save" (change back to viewer mode) the display are messed up.

We have tested create new pages at root site's Pages library and the result is good. Test created in subsite Pages library, the display are messed up.

What could be the issue. Did I missed anything?

Comment: May be you can get some reference from here - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f66abe2-7890-479b-b38b-349d3d1937d5/publishing-html-and-richtextfield-display-html-code-not-rendering?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly my problem and solution. At the beginning I had added columns to the sub site Pages library, and then add the custom content type. It messed up. So I remove all custom columns, remove the custom content type, then re-add the content type. This time the custom columns automatically added to sub site Pages library. All pages are rendering correctly!

Comment: Glad to help you. Please mark the answer so that it will help others in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add type (**RichHtml field**) columns to a custom content type - and then add that content type to the site (rather than the individual columns) - it works.

Please refer this link - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7f66abe2-7890-479b-b38b-349d3d1937d5/publishing-html-and-richtextfield-display-html-code-not-rendering?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: I want to mention we need to add the "custom content type" not the "custom columns". In this way the "custom columns" linked with that "custom content type" will be automatically added. If we add "custom columns" first it will result in the error I mentioned.